# Simple Algorithm for Rotating CPM Adverts on a Web Site

Tags: ads, advertisement-server

We have a Website on which we would like to display CPM rotating adverts.
However, we have not been able to find a robust way of actually selecting and displaying such adverts.

We know there are complex algorithms spanning multiple pages of Differential equations and Integrals of Statistical computations - but all we are looking for is a simple way of showing such adverts so that they all get their fare share of views taking into account the same users in multiple different sessions or different users etc.

Are there any guidance on these and other issues such as in addition to displaying the ads also differentiating between premium and standard (for example if there are 2 ads on a page the one with the premium is displayed first etc.)

Would greatly appreciate anyone's assistance.

Comment: what ad server/ad network are you using? Is it google ad manager or in-house solution?

Comment: @ffeast We are trying to create our own!